# how to detect if the value of a struct field has changed in C?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, pointers, struct

so lets say I have a function which updates a struct field:

```
struct person {
    int age;
};
```

```
void update_struct (int value) {
    person->age = value;
}
```

I want to detect whether the value of the struct field has changed in another function.

```
void another_function () {
    
    if (there is a change in the value of the struct field 'age') {
        // do the following;
    }

}
```

I am struggling to write an if statement condition for that. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: keep track of what was the last value you knew and compare it to the actual value. if they differ, one has changed. update your expected value accordingly afterwards

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you trying to implement that involves possibly updating a struct, and later being unsure if it was updated?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't do this directly, either you keep a flag which you modify when you alter a field or you keep a copy of the struct and [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) it, just remember that alignment may place some padding in the struct to you must make sure that `sizeof(type) == sizeof(field1) + sizeof(field2) + ...`.

The latter solution wastes more memory but it has the advantage that it's blindly working unless you have pointers inside your `struct`.

Comment: `memcmp` is not reliable for testing whether a structure’s members have changed because it compares padding in the structure, which is allowed to change even when no members of the structure change.

Comment: You must make sure there's no padding by putting an `static_assert(sizeof(Person) == sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + fields)` but apart from that I used it extensively many times.

Comment: If the copy of the struct that is used for comparison is initialized with a call to `memcpy()` from the original struct, then you can be sure that `memcmp()` on the two structs will return zero unless a member has been modified

Comment: @WillisHershey: also `memset` it to zero as initialization is a nice way to solve the issue